# ChromeDriver with headless raises ElementNotVisibleException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am new in selenium. I need a browser without a graphical interface because the project will start with Jenkins. I decided to use ChromeDriver in Headdless mode.

When I use ChrimeDriver in normal mode, I can click on all elements:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
List<WebElement> allElem = driver.findElements(By.ByXPath("//div[@id='accordian']/div/ul/li"));

for(int i=0; i<allElem.getSize(); i++){
   allElem.get(i).click(); // is ok
}
```

But when I use Headdless mode then I have: ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible. What could be wrong? Thank you for every clue.

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    //chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    List<WebElement> allElem = driver.findElements(By.ByXPath("//div[@id='accordian']/div/ul/li"));

    for(int i=0; i<allElem.getSize(); i++){
        allElem.get(i).click();//ElementNotVisibleException dont see next li elements 
        //div[@id='accordian']/div/ul/li
    }
```

Comment: Can you uncomment the line `chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");` and retest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While working with *Selenium Client v3.11.0*, *Chrome Driver v2.36* and *Chrome Browser v65.x* in *Headless Mode*, you need to pass the following arguments through an instance of *ChromeOptions* Class while initializing the *WebDriver* and the *Web Browser* as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `"--headless"`, chrome option like below.

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

For entire list of chrome options, refer the following URL. It explains every command line switches in detail.

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

While working with headless mode, I encountered `org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException` due to not handling popping out of Alert Boxes. So it is better if you could handle the alert boxes.

```
                    String alertText = alert.getText();
                    System.out.println("ERROR: (ALERT BOX DETECTED) - ALERT MSG : " + alertText);
                    alert.accept();
                    File outputFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
                    String imageDetails = "D://Images"
                    File screenShot = new File(imageDetails).getAbsoluteFile();
                    FileUtils.copyFile(outputFile, screenShot);
                    System.out.println("Screenshot saved: {}" + imageDetails);
                    driver.close();
```